# create a summary of movements between prices by date in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which shows; 1) dates, prices and 3) the difference between two prices by row.

```
dates | data | result     | change
24-09    24      0           none
25-09    26      2           pos
26-09    27      1           pos
27-09    28      1           pos
28-09    26     -2           neg
```

I want to create a summary of the above data in a new dataframe. The summary would have 4 columns: 1) start date, 2) end date 3) number of days 4) run

For example using the above there was a positive run of +4 from 25-09 and 27-09, so I would want this in a row of a dataframe like so:

In the new dataframe there would be one new row for every change in the value of result from positive to negative. Where run = 0 this indicates no change from the previous days price and would also need its own row in the dataframe.

```
start date | end date | num days | run 
 25-09        27-09        3        4         
 27-09        28-09        1        -2
 23-09        24-09        1        0
```

The first step I think would be to create a new column "change" based on the value of run which then shows either of: "positive","negative" or "no change". Then maybe I could groupby this column.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of useful functions for this style of problem are diff() and cumsum().

I added some extra datapoints to your sample data to flesh out the functionality.

The ability to pick and choose different (and more than one) aggregation functions assigned to different columns is a super feature of pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['24-09', '25-09', '26-09', '27-09', '28-09', '29-09', '30-09','01-10','02-10','03-10','04-10'],
                    'data': [24, 26, 27, 28, 26,25,30,30,30,28,25],
                    'result': [0,2,1,1,-2,0,5,0,0,-2,-3]})

def cat(x):
    return 1 if  x > 0 else -1 if x < 0 else 0

df['cat'] =  df['result'].map(lambda x : cat(x)) # probably there is a better way to do this

df['change'] = df['cat'].diff()  
df['change_flag'] = df['change'].map(lambda x: 1 if x != 0 else x)
df['change_cum_sum'] = df['change_flag'].cumsum() # which gives us our groupings


foo = df.groupby(['change_cum_sum']).agg({'result' : np.sum,'dates' : [np.min,np.max,'count'] })
foo.reset_index(inplace=True)
foo.columns = ['id','start date','end date','num days','run' ]
print foo
```

which yields:

```
   id start date end date  num days  run
0   1      24-09    24-09         1    0
1   2      25-09    27-09         3    4
2   3      28-09    28-09         1   -2
3   4      29-09    29-09         1    0
4   5      30-09    30-09         1    5
5   6      01-10    02-10         2    0
6   7      03-10    04-10         2   -5
```